# Javascript switch statement with months

Tags: javascript

I have a assignment where the user puts in a number inside a prompt box and the month comes out. Here is code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = prompt("enter a month number please.");

var b = "";

    switch(a){
        case 1: b = "January";
            break;
        case 2: b = "February";
            break;
        case 3: b = "March";
            break;
        case 4: b = "April";
            break;
        case 5: b = "May";
            break;
        case 6: b = "June"; 
            break;
        case 7: b = "July";
            break;
        case 8: b = "August";
            break;
        case 9: b = "September";
            break;
        case 10: b = "October";
            break;
        case 11: b = "November";
            break;
        case 12: b = "December";
            break;
        }

if((a==12) || (a==1) || (a==2)){

    document.write(" It is " + a + ", which is in winter.")
}

if((a==3) || (a==4) || (a==5)){

    document.write(" It is " + a + ", which is in spring.")
}

if((a==6) || (a==7) || (a==8)){

    document.write(" It is " + a + ", which is in summer.")
}

if((a==9) || (a==10) || (a==11)){

    document.write(" It is " + a + ", which is in fall.")
}

</script>
```

My months are not the output. Instead, the number is my output. It seems my switch statement is being ignored and only doing the if statements. I am lost at what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should use an array.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `" It is " + b + ...`?

Answer (score 8):

You are using the variable containing the number instead of the variable that contains the string. Use `b` in the output:

```
document.write(" It is " + b + ", which is in winter.");
```

---

You can also write the code as:

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("enter a month number please."), 10);
var month = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var b = month[a - 1];
var season;
switch (a) {
  case 12:
  case 1:
  case 2: season = "winter"; break;
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5: season = "spring"; break;
  case 6:
  case 7:
  case 8: season = "summer"; break;
  case 9:
  case 10:
  case 11: season = "fall"; break;
}
document.write(" It is " + b + ", which is in " + season + ".");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ZuXmP/

Comment: Problem with that is the spot for the variable is empty. Neither the the name of the month or number appears as an output.

Comment: @user1725798: Right, you need to parse the string into a number. See the edit above.

Answer (score 2):

`b` contains the month string not `a` e.g.

```
document.write(" It is " + b + ", which is in fall.")
```

Answer (score 0):

> `document.write(" It is " + a + ", which is in winter.")`

You used "a" instead of "b" in the document.write

Answer (score 0):

Much more efficient:

```
months = [["January",0],["February",0],["March",1]]; // Too tired to finish this array.
season = ["winter","spring","summer","fall"];

var a = prompt("Enter a month number please.");

if(!a.isNaN)
{
document.write(" It is " + months[a][0]  + ", which is in "+season[months[a][1]] +".")
}
```

Léon

Answer (score 0):

Math is cool too:

```
var a = prompt("enter a month number please.");
var months = [
  "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"
];
var seasons = ["winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"];
if (a == 12) a = 0;

document.write(" It is " + months[a] + ", which is in " + seasons[Math.floor(a/3)] + ".");​
```

Or you could write:

```
var a = prompt("enter a month number please.") % 12; // december is now 0, each other month remains the same.
var months = [
  "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"
];
var seasons = ["winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"];

document.write(" It is " + months[a] + ", which is in " + seasons[Math.floor(a/3)] + ".");​
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried commenting on Guffa's answer, but I cannot due to my low ranking. user1725798 try this. Prompt returns a string and you were initially comparing against a number. You need to parse the string.

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("enter a month number please."));

if (!a) {
   return;
}

var month = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var b = month[a - 1];
var season;
switch (a) {
    case 12:
    case 1:
    case 2: season = "winter"; break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: season = "spring"; break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8: season = "summer"; break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11: season = "fall"; break;
}
document.write(" It is " + b + ", which is in " + season + ".");
```